# Get current year in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

I have data I am trying to pull for a report and I am working on a Year to Date report. My columns in the table are formatted as datetime. I am trying to run a select statement to get all the results where date = this year.

For example:

```
SELECT  A.[id], A.[classXML]
FROM   tuitionSubmissions as A
WHERE A.[status] = 'Approved' AND A.[reimbursementDate] = THISYEAR
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Is there an eay way to acomplish this?

Comment: `Year(GetDate())` get you the current year

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Yes, it's remarkably easy in fact:

```
WHERE YEAR(A.[reimbursementDate]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Comment: The easy way is not the most efficient way though. That isn't sargable.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Absolutely true, but I'm not staring at his SQL Server instance to know if it matters.  Perhaps he only has 30,000 records at which point it won't matter because the amount of data is so small.  A fair point to make though!

Answer (score 8):

This should be a better way if performance is an issue (although it isn't as readable)

```
where A.[reimbursementDate] between  
     DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0) and
     DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))
```

Those funky DATEADD statements return the first and last days of the current year (through December 31 23:59:59.997).  Since `reimbursementDate` isn't contained in a function, the query will be able to take advantage of any applicable indexes.