# Number Format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a unique ID in my SQL Server table. The ID contains the year and an incremented number,

`2020-000001, 2020-000002` and it will restart its counting whenever the first year starts, for example when 2021 enters. Does anyone have an idea how?

Comment: First consider carefully whether this is really a requirement. Is there actually a problem if 2021 simply continues the incrementing id?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid not really... but the organization recruits new members every year. and yes, it's a requirement for the client.

Comment: Basically, using an `IDENTITY` is the simplest most robust solution for this but it doesn't reset every year. Implementing a counter that resets every year is additional development and complexity and therefore COST.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid alright, i think that will help, thanks.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: one might argue that using a `SEQUENCE` has almost the same benefits as an `IDENTITY` column, and a sequence can easily be reset at the start of a new year, back to 1. [For detail see the MS Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @marc_s Even better, you can have a different sequence for each year. So you can start entering 2020 documents while they still arrive delayed 2019 documents.

Comment: To me it's a question of complexity. An `IDENTITY` solution has no complexity, it just works. Rolling over a sequence every year by whatever means requires business logic of some description. Weigh this against the question of "is this really required or did someone just think it would look good"

Comment: and yes a SQL Agent job scheduled for 12:01 am every year seems simple but... time zones? Server down? Agent not started? It's just extra complexity that is actually unnecessary if it's not really a requirement. Every piece of added complexity invites bugs

Answer (score 0):

It is a generally accepted standard practice to use an id and theory suggests that fields must be atomic. Your unique key is by definition composite, because it consists of a year and a sequence number.

Nevertheless, you need a primary key and I suggest that the given primary key must be numeric. There are obvious benefits of doing so and I'm not going into their details now for the sake of simplicity.

However, I understand your need to have that unique identifier, which you could always compute (by counting the records created earlier in the year than the record and adding one to it), but that would perform badly. So, in this case it makes sense to make a slight compromise to normal form theory and use a composite field, which consists of the year and a sequence number and to use a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in order to always determine the value that you need. At the start of each year you can [restart the sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Now, you can create a before insert trigger for a record, which will [compute the year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963580/get-current-year-in-tsql) and concatenate a string of the format you described and set that value to your column. In general, this kind of stuff is needed for invoicing and you can create an index for this field for quick searches, but, again, I recommend the creation of another, numeric field which will be the primary key.